# automatically justify text within a nested description environment LyX

Tags: lyx, lists, description

I am trying to use LyX to generate the following.

[image]

I am using LyX, article class and the enumitem package.

I would like to have the text information in the lists to be aligned automatically by determining the length of the longest label.

Here is the MWE code.

```
 \documentclass{article}
 \usepackage{enumitem}
 \begin{document}
   \begin{description}[labelwidth=4cm]
     \item [{Description1}] Here is the first description.
        \begin{description}[labelwidth=5cm]
          \item [{NestedDescription1}] $a+b=c$ This is the first nested description.
          \item [{NestedD2}] This is the second nested description.
          \item [{NDescription3}] This is the third nested description.
        \end{description}
     \item [{Des2}] This is the second shorter label description.
   \end{description}
 \end{document}
```